# Efficiently make iterative LINQ to SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to implement the following algorithm using LINQ-to-SQL:

Given a list of strings L, return every row R in the DB for which every string in L is a substring of one of the column values in R.

The question is how do I do this iteratively for every string in L? I don't know how I can slickly put it all into one Linq-To-SQL statement. Note that I have no problem writing code along the lines of:

`field1.contains(...) || field2.contains(...) || ...`

as there are not that many columns.

E.g., if the input is

> ["Charlie", "Doctor", "Kor"]

we would output all rows that have a field with "Charlie" as a substring, a field with "Doctor" as a substring, and a field with "Kor" as a substring.

One approach I thought of was to make separate SQL queries for each input value and to take the intersection of all of those.

Another approach is to pick just one of the strings from the input, make a SQL query on that, convert it to a list, and filter out the rest of the strings one at a time using just LINQ in C#.

Any thoughts on an optimal way to do this?

Comment: Why not make one query, put the stuff in where? .Where(r => r.MyField.Contains("Doctor") || r.MyField.Contains("Charlie") || ...)

Comment: I think the point he's getting at is, he doesn't want to manually check every column.  He's looking for a way to check all columns.  Your suggestion for the individual where's is correct though.  It would work.

Comment: The issue isn't manually checking every column, I'm happy to do that as there are O(1) columns. But how can I do .Where(r => r.MyField.Contains("Doctor") || r.MyField.Contains("Charlie") || ...) in Linq-To-SQL if my input is an array? What would that look like syntactically?

Comment: Please incorporate your last comment into question, because the way it is now is unclear what are you asking.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method (EF6 supports it, not sure about LINQ to SQL):

```
List<string> values = new List<string> { "Charlie", "Doctor", "Kor" };
var query = db.Table
    .Where(r => values.All(v => r.Field1.Contains(v) || r.Field2.Contains(v) || ...));
```

**Update:** Well, the assumption was wrong - as mentioned in the comments, unfortunately LINQ to SQL does not support the above construct (shame on them).

As usual in such cases, I would build dynamically a corresponding predicate expression.

In this particular case we need something like this (for `N` fields and `M` values):

```
r => (r.Field1.Contains(value1) || r.Field2.Contains(value1) ... || r.FieldN.Contains(value1))
  && (r.Field1.Contains(value2) || r.Field2.Contains(value2) ... || r.FieldN.Contains(value2))
  ...
  && (r.Field1.Contains(valueM) || r.Field2.Contains(valueM) ... || r.FieldN.Contains(valueM));
```

And here is a custom extension method which does that:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereContainsAll<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, 
        IEnumerable<string> values,
        params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] members)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "r");
        var body = values
            .Select(value => members
                .Select(member => (Expression)Expression.Call(
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member),
                    "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(value)))
                .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse))
            .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

and the sample usage would be

```
List<string> values = new List<string> { "Charlie", "Doctor", "Kor" };
var query = db.Table.WhereContainsAll(values,
    r => r.Field1, r => r.Field2, r => r.Field3, ...);
```

which should lead to a single SQL query which IMO should be optimal because the heavy work will be done by the database engine. Of course the query most likely will cause full table scan, but the same will happen even with single `Contains` (SQL `LIKE`) criteria.

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunately I'm getting a NotSupportedException:
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: Argh, too bad :( But just to confirm, this is what are you looking for, just need to find a way making it work?

Comment: Yep. The goal is to maximize efficiency and my assumption is that the more work I give SQL vs C# post-processing, the better it will be.

Comment: great example of generating complex expression dynamically -

Answer (score -1):

Try this (I made an example using Lists):

```
var dbValues = new List<string> {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
var substrings = new List<string> {"ello", "re"};

var result = dbValues.Where(i => substrings.Any(l => i.Contains(l))).ToList();
```

Result will contain {"**hello**","**are**"}

Example with database:

```
using (var db = new MyDatabase())
{
    var substrings = new List<string> { "ello", "re" };
    var result = db.MyTable.Where(i => substrings.Any(l => i.Value.Contains(l))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The query provider isn't going to know how to translate that into SQL.  The question isn't asking about querying an in memory list; it's asking about querying a database.

Comment: ok, if someone has problem in translating that logic to SQL, here it is: using (var db = new DB())
            {
                var substrings = new List<string> { "ello", "re" };
                var result = db.MyTable.Where(i => substrings.Any(l => i.Value.Contains(l))).ToList();
            }

Comment: That's not SQL...that's just a LINQ query that will error when run, because the query provider won't be able to translate it into SQL, as mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: I know that is not the generated SQL, but when you run this, you can catch generated SQL using profiler.

Comment: No, when you run it you'll see your program crash because the query provider can't translate it into SQL, like I've told you twice now.